# Deadlock при использовании wait и notify

Tags: java, многопоточность

Сегодня приступил к изучению многопоточности на java, не понимаю, почему программа в некоторых случаях выдает корректный результат, а в остальных deadlock.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы обеспечить многоразовый вывод на консоль сначала "I throw a ball", а затем "I got a ball" с использованием wait и notify. Также необходимо получать корректный результат независимо от того, какой поток выполнения стартует первым.

```
package main;
import java.util.Random;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

     NBAPlayer Oneil = new NBAPlayer();
    Sender sender = new Sender(Oneil);
    Getter getter = new Getter(Oneil);



    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(sender,"sender ");
        Thread th = new Thread(getter,"getter ");t.start();

        Random random = new Random();
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(500)+500);
        th.start();
    }
}


static class Sender implements Runnable
{
    NBAPlayer Oneil ;
    public Sender(NBAPlayer oneil) {
        Oneil = oneil;
    }
    public void run() {

        try {
            Oneil.throwBall();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

static class Getter implements Runnable
{
    NBAPlayer Oneil ;

    public Getter(NBAPlayer oneil) {
        Oneil = oneil;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            Oneil.getBall();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

static class NBAPlayer
{
    public volatile boolean ready = false;

    public synchronized void throwBall() throws InterruptedException {
        while(ready==false) {
            System.out.println("I throw a ball");
            ready=true;
            notify();
        }

    }

    public synchronized void getBall() throws InterruptedException {
        while(ready==false)
        {
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println("I got your ball");
        ready=false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Это классическая задача producer-consumer. У Шилдта она очень хорошо и подробно расписана.

Comment: Подумайте, что будет если два потока Sender отработают подряд.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ был найден в книге Герберта Шилдта  - "Java 8. Полное руководство".

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        NBAPlayer Oneil = new NBAPlayer();
        Sender sender = new Sender(Oneil);
        Getter getter = new Getter(Oneil);


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(sender, "sender ");
            Thread th = new Thread(getter, "getter ");

            t.start();
            Random random = new Random();
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(500) + 500);
            th.start();
        }

    }


    static class Sender implements Runnable {
        NBAPlayer Oneil;

        public Sender(NBAPlayer oneil) {
            Oneil = oneil;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                Oneil.throwBall();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    static class Getter implements Runnable {
        NBAPlayer Oneil;

        public Getter(NBAPlayer oneil) {
            Oneil = oneil;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                Oneil.getBall();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    static class NBAPlayer {
        public volatile boolean ready = false;

        public synchronized void throwBall() throws InterruptedException {
            while (ready) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("I throw a ball");
            ready = true;
            notify();
        }

        public synchronized void getBall() throws InterruptedException {
            while (!ready) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("I got a ball");
            ready = false;
            notify();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: while(ready==false) - зачем? - это же явный булев тип, зачем его сравнивать? while(!ready).

Comment: Вы правы, незачем, дело в моей неопытности. Сейчас исправлю.